# Version Control as Text File?

Tags: c, eclipse, version-control

I am using eclipse and would like to integrate some sort of version control. Ideally, I do not want to use a plugin. I would really like to somehow write the version to a text file in some way.

The reason I would like to do this is because I have a program that needs to track the current version of the workspace. Right now I am manually creating a text file in the workspace folder called "Version.XXXX" and just reading the name of the file to get the version number. However, I would like to somehow have eclipse do this automatically in case I forget to make the text file manually.

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: git, subversion, or cvs are three well-known open source version control systems

Comment: *"Ideally, I do not want to use a plugin."*  In other words, "I know other people have already solved this problem but I would rather solve it again, in a very inferior way."  If you are trying to avoid having to set up a VCS server, at least try EGit; Git repositories can be just a directory and don't have to exist remotely.

Comment: You say automatically, but when and how? When do you want Eclipse to increment your version number? And from where, from comments in your source code? By guessing?

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies. I will look at EGit. I would like to increment the version number whenever I update the workspace.

Comment: Why not using a time-stamp? You do not need to create it or update it. Time flows by itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple source version control system I suggest you use Mercurial. All the versioning information is stored in the root folder of your project in a `.hg` folder. There is no server and log-ins. Like SVN and Git, it has gui support from Tortoise and plug-in for your IDE. The logic and commands behind it are similar to other solutions.